# PYTHON - Random Choice

Tags: python, authentication, random

I have built a game and I need to use `random.choice`:

When a user logs in, they needs to go into one of 15 rooms, chosen at random. How does one modify the following code to use `random.choice` to choose a room?

```
#login
self.enterRoom("1")
```

Comment: @user1704332.. You don't need to sorry for something that is not required to have good concept.. :).. And frankly speaking.. that's not a bad english at all..

Answer (score 7):

Not using `random.choice`,
 using `random.randint` :

```
import random
room = random.randint(1,15)
```

Comment: Hi Caner! That would be "1" to "15" ? Or just 1 to 15?

Comment: @user1704332 it will be ints, not strings. You should convert it to string if needed with the str() method.

Comment: @user1704332 How about reading the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.randint)? If things are unclear after reading the docs, by all means ask, but you should try to figure it out for yourself first.

Answer (score 3):

You almost certainly don't want to use `random.choice` for this; Caner Korkmaz's answer is much better.

But if for some reason you really need to use `random.choice` (e.g., because it's a homework assignment and your professor insisted), see [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html):

> random.choice(seq)
>
> Return a random element from the non-empty sequence seq. If seq is empty, raises IndexError.

So, you need to get a sequence that contains the strings "1" to "15". To do that:

```
rooms = [str(i) for i in range(1, 16)]
```

Then:

```
room = random.choice(rooms)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this.  Just choose the one that is most convenient for your situation and that you find to be the most readable.

The *random.choice()* method works great when you population of eligible choices is already in a list:

```
>>> rooms = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15']
>>> random.choice(rooms)
'7'
```

The *random.randrange()* function works when the choices are numeric and contiguous (though you will still have to call *str* afterwards):

```
>>> str(random.randrange(1, 16))
'2'
```

For a computer science point of view that last one is the most elegant; however, in terms of clearly expressing the intent of the code in a game, the first one wins by saying "make a random choice of the available rooms".